# Under what condition(s) is a linear differential delay system "weakly controllable"?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, linear-control, system-identification

I am trying to understand the conditions under which the parameters of a linear differential delay system are identifiable. I am reading this 2002 paper by Belkoura and Orlov: [Identifiability analysis of linear time-delay systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/980962). The following is paraphrasing:

The system

$ {\dot{x} }\left( t\right) =\Sigma _{i=0}^{r}A_{i}x\left( t-\tau_{i}\right) +\sum ^{l}_{i=0}B_{i}u\left( t-\tau _{i}\right) $

can be represented over the ring of polynomials $R[\lambda]$ as:

$ {\dot{x} }\left( t\right) =A(\lambda)x(t) + B(\lambda)u(t)$

where $ \lambda=[\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k] $ and $k$ is the max. number of non-commensurable time delay units in the system.

My understanding from Belkoura and Orlov is that the above system is identifiable if it is "weakly controllable" and if the input $u(t)$ is sufficiently rich. The latter, I understand, can be achieved if the input function has at least $(k+p)$ non-commensurable discontinuities of jump size $\neq 0$, where $p$ is the dimension of the input function. But, how can I tell if a system is weakly controllable?
Also, please correct any misunderstandings above if you spot any - this is quite outside my usual field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weak controllability simply consists of the satisfiability of the Kalman rank condition of the time-delay systems when the matrices of the system take values in some ring of operators associated with the delay operators.

In other words, the system is weakly controllable if

$$\mathrm{rank}\begin{bmatrix}B(\lambda) & A(\lambda)B(\lambda)& \ldots & & A(\lambda)^{n-1}B(\lambda)\end{bmatrix}=n$$

and where the rank is taken over $R[\lambda]$.

For more information, you may look at the papers

1. Morse, "Ring Models for Delay-Differential Systems", Automatica
2. Sename, "New trends in design of observers for time-delay systems", Kybernetika
3. Lee, Neftci, and Olbrot, "Canonical Forms for Time Delay Systems", IEEE TAC
4. Fliess and Mounier, "Controllability and Observability of Linear Delay Systems: An Algebraic Approach, ESAIM Control Optimisation and Calculus of Variations.